# How to split MongoDB replicaset in two replica sets

Tags: mongodb

We have a mongoDB replicaset with 6 members (one master and 5 secondaries), split on two continents.

We need to create two replicasets from the big one. All members are in sync.

How can this be done?

Thank you.

Comment: I recommend reading http://mauro-stettler.blogspot.com/2013/02/splitting-one-mongodb-replicaset-into.html, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was indeed to mongodump, remove the other's continent nodes from cluster, and with those to create there a new replicaset, importing the data from the backup.

Thanks tom slabbaert. I thought that there is a simpler solution.